# Underful \hbox in template

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, warnings

I like to use this template:https://www.latextemplates.com/template/journal-article
I am using it in Overleaf and it compiles however I am shown in the logs that the \hboxes seem to be underfull? Despite compiling just fine these warnings cause annoying syntax highlighting bugs. How can I fix this?

The logs say:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 158--160
\T1/pplx/m/n/10 (+20) A state-ment re-quir-ing ci-ta-tion
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 158--160
\T1/pplx/m/n/10 (+20) [[]]. Lorem ip-
 []

[2]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1748) in paragraph at lines 172--176
[]\T1/pplx/m/n/10 (+20) Figueredo, A. J.
 []
```

This is the template

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Journal Article
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.4 (15/5/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Frits Wenneker (http://www.howtotex.com) with extensive modifications by
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template 

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} % Make itemize lists more compact

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Running title $\bullet$ May 2016 $\bullet$ Vol. XXI, No. 1} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries} % Article title formatting
\posttitle{\end{center}} % Article title closing formatting
\title{Article Title} % Article title
\author{%
\textsc{John Smith}\thanks{A thank you or further information} \\[1ex] % Your name
\normalsize University of California \\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
%\and % Uncomment if 2 authors are required, duplicate these 4 lines if more
%\textsc{Jane Smith}\thanks{Corresponding author} \\[1ex] % Second author's name
%\normalsize University of Utah \\ % Second author's institution
%\normalsize \href{mailto:jane@smith.com}{jane@smith.com} % Second author's email address
}
\date{\today} % Leave empty to omit a date
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \blindtext % Dummy abstract text - replace \blindtext with your abstract text
\end{abstract}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

% Print the title
\maketitle

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction}

\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{L} orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\blindtext % Dummy text

\blindtext % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

Maecenas sed ultricies felis. Sed imperdiet dictum arcu a egestas. 
\begin{itemize}
\item Donec dolor arcu, rutrum id molestie in, viverra sed diam
\item Curabitur feugiat
\item turpis sed auctor facilisis
\item arcu eros accumsan lorem, at posuere mi diam sit amet tortor
\item Fusce fermentum, mi sit amet euismod rutrum
\item sem lorem molestie diam, iaculis aliquet sapien tortor non nisi
\item Pellentesque bibendum pretium aliquet
\end{itemize}
\blindtext % Dummy text

Text requiring further explanation\footnote{Example footnote}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Name} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
First name & Last Name & Grade \\
\midrule
John & Doe & $7.5$ \\
Richard & Miles & $2$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext % Dummy text

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:emc}
e = mc^2
\end{equation}

\blindtext % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Discussion}

\subsection{Subsection One}

A statement requiring citation \cite{Figueredo:2009dg}.
\blindtext % Dummy text

\subsection{Subsection Two}

\blindtext % Dummy text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{thebibliography}{99} % Bibliography - this is intentionally simple in this template

\bibitem[Figueredo and Wolf, 2009]{Figueredo:2009dg}
Figueredo, A.~J. and Wolf, P. S.~A. (2009).
\newblock Assortative pairing and life history strategy - a cross-cultural
  study.
\newblock {\em Human Nature}, 20:317--330.

\end{thebibliography}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You say it "compiles fine" but the warnings are warning you of bad output.

eg the first is related to

[image]

where in order to justify the paragraph the white space on the first line  of the paragraph has had to be stretched beyond reasonable limits.

The second warning is also related to this fragment, the second line has white space around `Lorem` over-stretched.

You should ignore such warnings until the final stage of the document editing and if they are still there at the end, you can consider a minor re-wording or adding additional hyphenation points or a forced line break  or using a package that allows line breaks in hyperlinked citations or ... .

Comment: @manooooh thanks I deleted that text I think it was a left over part of a sentence sentence that I had re-worded before posting.